# Nginx Change Location on Specific Url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, url

I have this laravel directory stucture:

```
/app
...
[another-default-laravel-structure]
...
/dist
/public
```

My current Nginx setting is like this:

```
server {


    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name example.com;

    error_log /some/path/to/logs-file.log;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        root /home/user/laravel-project/dist;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    location /contact-us-send/ {
        root /home/user/laravel-project/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index    index.php;
        fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying pointing main path to "dist" directory. This directory is a static html generated using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-export. What I am to do is, on "contact-us-send", I need to process input from contact form to make it send an email. But everytime I try to submit the form, which is example.com/contact-us-send, it's always show 404 not found nginx default page.

Is there something I'm missing out?

Comment: What is the document root for the `location ~ \.php$` block? How do you process the form? Is is using PHP?

Comment: Error 404 for `/contact-us-send/` generally means at this location nginx can't find any index.php, index.html or index.htm file.